# How do I change the state of a button in a specific row of tableview

Tags: tableview

I have a `UITableView`, with a custom cell.  The custom cell has a button in it.

When the button is tapped I invoke method :

```
-(IBAction)accessoryLikeButtonTapped:(id)sender
```

In this method I do some processing.

So far so good.

I want to disable the button object in the row that was selected.  I have the row number as I pass it across in the tag property of the button.

I am just not sure of the syntax to get to the button object.

eg. `self.tableview.rowatindex(5).cell.button.enabled = NO;`

Comment: I tried this but it crashed (not unexpectedly) :

    [sender btnLike].enabled = NO;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your row is visible (should be since you pressed a button on it)

```
[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:n inSection:0]]
```

will return the cell you need (otherwise it will return nil).

Beware that you should keep track of this state in case the cell for this row is recreated after to disable the button on it again.